# how to convert joomla table to json php

Tags: json, joomla, encode

not getting correct output while converting joomla '_content' table. My php code:

```
<?php
 $hostname = "hostname";
 $username = "myusername";
 $dbname = "mydatabase";
 $password = "mypassword";

  mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
  connect to database! Please try again later.");
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `title`, `fulltext` FROM `jos_content` WHERE `catid`=8");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

It gives output as json file, but it is not displaying any data against 'fulltext' row. Output sample:

```
 [{"title":"Tu Jaane Na - Ajab Prem Ki Ghazab Kahani (Chords)","fulltext":""},
{"title":"Aahatein - Agnee (Chords)","fulltext":""}]
```

it is not retrieving any values from fulltext. Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `mysql_*`, as it's deprecated, switch to PDO or mysqli. Second, if you are doing this *inside* of Joomla, then use Joomla functions to work with the database, otherwise it's plain wrong.

`fulltext` will be empty if your articles don't have a "read more", everything will be stored in `introtext`. If you have a "read more" in an article, then intro will be in `introtext` and the rest in `fulltext`.

Comment: You are awesome. there was no read more in articles. I changed fulltext to introtext. But where there was '/strong' tag it shows '\/strong' . The json file created cannot be validated.

Comment: `json_encode` escapes it automatically. check [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), you can add option to remove automatic `/` escaping if you have php 5.4+. for example `json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: Thanks, I have php5.0. Well link to my json file: http://www.guitarmaddy.com/guitarmaddyapp/createhindichords.php .The json file is not validating. I am a beginner please help. how can I validate this file.

Comment: Solved the problem my php files contained html tags. I removed those and now my json file is validated.. Thanks all

Comment: Thanks all. Can you help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841816/xml-tag-link-to-other-tag-within-same-xml-jquery-phonegap  . I got no replies @Marko